# Bioshock Infinite Vigor Vending Machine

Tags: bioshock-infinite

I'm just at the part where Booker and the girl walk through a tear and Booker is suddenly a martyr for the vox.

I've been passing by veni vedi vigor machines for quite a while now, but the only upgrades they have are two devils kiss and one bucking bronco. I only want to upgrade my crow and shock jockey...but I'm just not seeing the upgrades in these machines? What's the deal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will be able to upgrade them later, just be patient. You unlock more upgrade for your first powers as the game progress

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks. Felt like I was almost done with the game.

Comment: @ShrimpCrackers You're not. You've got a bit to go.